# Base de Datos - Ordenar Tabla Por Indice | Index

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, orderby

Hola, buenas noches.

Tengo una duda, con respecto a los indices, es para ambos gestores, SQL y MySQL.

Tengo una **Tabla Personas**, en la que se guardan por dos tipos, **cliente** o **proveedor** y se almacenan los registros de acuerdo al orden en el que se ingresan. Al crear la tabla el orden es por la **Primary Key**. Pero quiero evitar realizar **"order by tipo_proveedor, numero, nombre"** sino que ya este definido de esta forma.

**¿Cómo podría estructura la tabla para que ya este ordenada y sea mas fácil y rápida la búsqueda?**

Lo que quiero lograr es algo así con los índices, sea orden ascendentes o descendentes, sin necesidad de usar el order by, con unique si se puede hacer, pero con los índices no agrupados, que supuestamente funcionan para hacer mas eficiente la consulta no lo he logrado.

**order by tipo_proveedor, numero, nombre**

**order by tipo_proveedor, numero desc, nombre**

**Tabla con el indice de la Primary Key**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla con el indice creado, se mantiene sin cambios**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla con la restricción Unique, ordena por tipo de persona, número y nombre, que es el orden que deseo que tenga la estructura de mi tabla, pero no quiero usar Unique en esta tabla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leído que los índices de la base de datos trabajan como el índice de un libro y devuelven las consultas de forma mas eficiente, pero sinceramente no encuentro la razón de como funcionan verdaderamente.

Siempre he optimizado mis consultas sin índices y he trabajado hasta con 100,000 registros, con más 40 columnas, aunque la mayor eficiencia que logre fue de 2 segundos. En algunos casos me ha ayudado haber estructura bien la tabla, haber definido correctamente los tipos de datos, las longitudes, relacionar correctamente los join, y otras veces las restricciones Unique, que solucionaban el problema porque era el orden que necesita y coincidían con el requerimiento de restringir el registro en base a esos campos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una pregunta doble.

1. Los indices en una tabla ordenan automáticamente los resultados?
2. No entiendo los índices de una tabla. Cómo funcionan?

Voy a responder la primera, y la segunda de forma vaga. Tienes mucha investigación que realizar.

> Pero quiero evitar realizar "order by tipo_proveedor, numero, nombre" sino que ya este definido de esta forma.

> Lo que quiero lograr es algo así con los índices, sea orden ascendentes o descendentes, sin necesidad de usar el order by, con unique si se puede hacer, pero con los índices no agrupados, que supuestamente funcionan para hacer mas eficiente la consulta no lo he logrado.

No es correcto que digas *con unique si se puede hacer*. No veo en la documentación de UNIQUE INDEX de MySQL que diga que automáticamente ordena los resultados. La consulta no puede volver automáticamente ordenada basada en los índices.

Por qué?

Las operaciones de los motores de bases de datos relacionales (MySQL, SQL Server, etc...), están basados, mayormente, en la Teoría de Conjuntos donde el orden **no es importante**. Por lo tanto, los RDBMS **de ninguna manera garantizan** el ordenamiento de los resultados. Los índices no tienen NADA que ver con el orden de los resultados. El orden es importante para nosotros, los humanos. Para las mátemáticas, no.

### No entiendo los índices de una tabla. Cómo funcionan?

Dependiendo del motor que utilices, la implementación de los índices pueden cambiar.
Para [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html) los índices son mayormente utilizados para mejorar la velocidad de las consultas porque cada registro en **el índice** es un puntero que apunta directamente a la fila **en la tabla** que tiene los datos que buscas.

Los índices son, literalmente, estructuras físicas que van junto a la tabla que tiene los datos, por lo tanto ocupan espacio.

Imagina el siguiente escenario. Tienes una tabla no-indexada con todas las órdenes de envío de Amazon. Imagina que la tabla tiene 5 mil millones de registros. Imagina que buscas un número de orden específico (3,000,000,000). El RDBMS deberá hacer lo que se conoce como un Full Table Scan para saber dónde exactamente está el registro que buscas. Buscará entre los registros UNO POR UNO para encontrar el que busca.

Ahora imagina que tienes un índice sobre el número de orden.

Entonces, **literalmente**, existe una estructura donde el RDBMS puede realizar una [búsqueda binaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_binaria), es decir, si buscas la orden 3,000,000,000, el motor busca:

Primero la mitad del índice, compara el valor obtenido (2,500,000,000) y se da cuenta que la orden que buscas está después. Entonces, descarta todas las que están antes.

Luego, busca la mitad de las ordenes restantes, este numero es 3,750,000,000 y se da cuenta que la orden de compra está antes, y descarta todas las siguientes.

Luego, continúa esta búsqueda hasta que llega al número de orden correcta. En lugar de buscar entre 5 mil millones de registros, sólo tuvo que realizar la búsqueda binaria en el índice, que es órdenes de magnitud más rápida. Una vez que encuentra el valor buscado en el índice, éste tiene un puntero que apunta directamente a la fila que contiene la información en la tabla de orden de compra.

Recuerda que para que un índice sea útil, debe ir en la cláusula WHERE de la consulta. De nada sirve tener un índice en el número de orden, si buscas las órdenes por fecha. En este caso, mejor pones un índice sobre las coumna fecha.

Espero esto pueda aclarar un poco la confusión acerca de los índices que muchos desarrolladores tenemos en nuestra vida. Esta explicación es heredada y me ayudó a mí a entender mejor los índices.

Comment: Gracias, por la aclaración, tenia muchas dudas sobre los índices. He estado equivocado, por que cada vez que usaba una restricción unique y realizaba un select * from tabla, me traía los resultados ordenados en base a los campos de la restricción. Y pensé que los índices no agrupados podrían darme el mismo resultado y asi evitaria realizar un order by.